# Click a link having same class among other classes and same link name among other link name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to click on this link automatically. the href and data-id is generated randomly on website. and also have other links on website which have same class and same link name.

I want to click the first link among the other similar link on the webpage.

```
 <a class="btn btn-success btn-mini bid-now ProjectTable-control" href="www.example.com/random" data-id="13033246">Bid Now</a>
```

Here are some more code for better understanding:

```
<td class=" ProjectTable-cell ProjectTable-priceColumn price-col"><span class="average-bid">$2400</span><div class="ProjectTable-controls">
    <a class="btn btn-success btn-mini bid-now ProjectTable-control" href="/projects/view_new.php?id=13033253#placebid" data-id="13033253">
        Bid Now
    </a>





        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-mini repost ProjectTable-control" data-ttref="PostProject_ProjectListingLoggedIn" data-type="p" data-qts="PostProject" data-id="13033253" href="https://www.example.com/buyers/repost.php?id=13033253">
            Post a project like this
        </a>
```

Comment: What do you want to do? Please be more specific.

Comment: why you dont just assign an id to the anchor?

Comment: I have to work on a website and click same link whole day so i want to automate it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question does not follow the guidelines here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask I think you need to look at how to automate your workflow, try googling "automating clicks on a web site" and you'll find a bunch of resources to look at

Comment: Mikkel, I have done a lots of search and tried various code but nothing helped me. now i have no option other then taking a help from expert from here. sorry if it breaks the terms and condition of this forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.getElementsByClassName('bid-now ProjectTable-control')[0].click()
```

Comment: How can i assign id attribute? there are around 10 similar links on the website.

Comment: how do yourself decide which link to click/>?

Comment: Are links randomly generated by your code ? @AnkitGoel

Comment: not randomly. there are 10 same links in the website and i click on the very first link.

Comment: i have added some more code. i hope that will help.

Comment: it didn't work, I'm getting following error in console

 => TypeError: libnotify is undefined[Learn More]

 => Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function (b){return window.libnotify=window.libnotify||a(b)} http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch

 => TypeError: this.$listingTypeControl.select2 is not a function

I'm using noConflict function already

Comment: is your site on live? can you give me the link

Comment: its https://www.freelancer.com/jobs but the page will not show link button until you create your account. i can create a dummy account if you need.

Comment: jQuery seem not working, try document.getElementsByClassName('bid-now ProjectTable-control')[0].click()  @AnkitGoel

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName('bid-now ProjectTable-control')[0].click()  this works. Thank you